# undefined value for getting checkbox value ,in if statement?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, checkbox, undefined

I ve faced a problem in jq ! I m trying to get checked checkboxes (its an array) by its name ! so everything is ok ,till I use if statement ! in if statement its undefined ! see here :

```
 $('#editSub').click(function(){
var $nameGiven=$('#editPlz').attr('name');
//here I got the values ! 
var values = new Array();
$.each($("input[name='status[]']:checked"), function() {
  values.push($(this).val());
});

//this alert give forexample 102,103
alert(values);


if($nameGiven == 'status[]'){
  //but here its undefined !!!!!! whyyy ?????
  alert(values);
}
}
```

help me plz ! thanks in advance

Comment: Any chance you can post HTML code that includes your `#editSub`element and your inputs to test it in a JavaScript sandbox?

Comment: [its fiddle link ,check the problem here !](https://jsfiddle.net/s43k68xd/6/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know without seeing your full code.
make sure that you have an element with id="editPlz" and a name attribute.
This code works:

```js
$("document").ready(function () { 
    $('#editSub').click(function () {
        var $nameGiven = $('#editPlz').attr('name');
        //here I got the values ! 
        var values = new Array();
        $.each($("input[name='status[]']:checked"), function () {
            values.push($(this).val());
        });

        //this alert give forexample 102,103
        alert(values);

        if ($nameGiven == 'status[]') {
            //but here its undefined !!!!!! whyyy ?????
            alert(values);
        }
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" name="status[]" value="1"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="status[]" value="2"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="status[]" value="3"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="status[]" value="4"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="status[]" value="5"/>
    
    <input type="checkbox" name="status[]" id="editPlz" />

    <input type="button" id="editSub" value="click"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: see js fiddle link that I put in comments plz , tnx.

Comment: yes u are right , inputs are in while in php , and I remove editPlz id after I ecountered this error, so I remove it and change a bit ... but I didnt add editPlz id ! that was silly mistake , thanks a lot .